# Voltage Controller Pulse Delay

Tags: voltage, delay, controller

I want to make, as simples as possible, a circuit that I could control how much delay it can add to a pulse.

My goal is to make a anti-wheeling system for motorcycle with cdi.

It basically sends a pulse to the coil, I need to delay it based on a input sensor that goes on the front wheel, doing so it wheel delay the ignition spark prevent the wheeling.

Is there a way to do it without a microcontroller?

Comment: Yes.  Do you want to delay the end of a pulse once it has been started (variable pulse width), or delay the entire pulse but keep its width constant (variable onset)?

Comment: Where are your specs and tolerances?

Comment: The front wheel lifts, the engine is retarded, front wheel drops, engine goes back to full power. Rinse and repeat. That would be one wild ride. Somehow I’m thinking you need something a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: Yes, use the pulse to start a timer circuit that starts charging a capacitor. Use a comparator to compare the capacitor's voltage to the sensor's output. When the capacitor's voltage exeeds the sensor's voltage, trigger the coil.

Comment: The delay is never fixed but rather phase of the RPM frequency

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 this is what I need, it should delay the phase of the RPM frequency...

Comment: @Kartman I test this with another motorcycle, this one has programmable ECU, and it works perfect, the front wheel dont come out of the road, beacuse the sensor is mounted on the fork, so the suspension lift just a bit, and the system start to delay the ignition point

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  but how can I tune this to control with the sensor input? Do you have an schematic?

Comment: *but how can I tune this to control with the sensor input?* With a (variable gain) amplifier between sensor and comparator. I could only draw a schematic after I have **lots** more details and requirements. My idea is that I suggest an architecture and that **you** draw / design the schematic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'll think some how, maybe a 555 could do the job. basically the signal is a pulse base on motorcycle RPM and the sensor is an IR distance sensor, the idea is control how much delay is add based on distance from the road

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics. After input pulse come the SR output is set to high so the C1 starts charging. When the C1 voltage reaches sensor voltage (adjusted with R3,R4) the comparator output is set to high what triggers the 1st one shot which generates the ouput pulse (blue). This pulse also triggers the 2nd one shot (after little time defined with 10k,1n) to reset SR to be ready for next input pulse.

[image]

If you want just cut from beginning of input pulse the solution is easiest (below). A good approach is to set compare level (R3,R4) on inverting input to 2/3 of input pulse voltage where C1 charges relatively linearly, so if you use a 5v logic set R3,R4 to around 3v at sensor maximum.
If the input pulse voltage is not presise use a zener diode on input (5v1) so the C1 will charge with constant voltage.

[image]

For 5v logic with zener input clamp it could be (delay time is set with C1):

[image]